# Why is Daemon compilation failed?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Good evening everyone,
I'm a beginner at Flutter while I was running my application I got a long error but my apk is running too the error is

```
e: Daemon compilation failed: null
java.lang.Exception
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.CompileService$CallResult$Error.get(CompileService.kt:69)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.CompileService$CallResult$Error.get(CompileService.kt:65)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.compileWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:244)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.compileWithDaemonOrFallbackImpl(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:175)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.run(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:135)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction.execute(GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers.kt:73)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:170)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
```

My gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip
```

my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

My Java installed version 21

Thanks